# Swift 3.1 Issue with SKCloudServiceCapability

Tags: ios, swift, apple-music

I'm trying to call this function to check Apple Music subscription status. I have an active subscription and listen to music on my iPhone.
But when I'm running test app on it, `capability` value is not valid.

It should be `SKCloudServiceCapability.musicCatalogPlayback`, `SKCloudServiceCapability.addToCloudMusicLibrary`, or not set. I can only get `raw value = 257`.

```
func appleMusicCheckIfDeviceCanPlayback()
{
    let serviceController = SKCloudServiceController()
    serviceController.requestCapabilities { (capability:SKCloudServiceCapability, err:Error?) in
        switch capability {
        case SKCloudServiceCapability.musicCatalogPlayback:
            print("The user has an Apple Music subscription and can playback music!")
        case SKCloudServiceCapability.addToCloudMusicLibrary:
            print("The user has an Apple Music subscription, can playback music AND can add to the Cloud Music Library")
        case []:
            print("The user doesn't have an Apple Music subscription available. Now would be a good time to prompt them to buy one?")
        default: print("Something went wrong")
        }
    }
}
```

---

[image: screenshot]

---

What's wrong here?

Comment: Asked the same on Apple Development Forums:
https://forums.developer.apple.com/message/228739#228739

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Finally guys from Apple Forums gave me this link to documentation and  I have found the issue.
https://developer.apple.com/library/content/qa/qa1929/_index.html

I should use if capability.contains(SKCloudServiceCapability.) instead of switch for capability value.
So this code works pretty fine.

```
func appleMusicCheckIfDeviceCanPlayback()  
{  
    let serviceController = SKCloudServiceController()  
    serviceController.requestCapabilities { (capability:SKCloudServiceCapability, err:Error?) in  
        if capability.contains(SKCloudServiceCapability.musicCatalogPlayback) {  
            print("The user has an Apple Music subscription and can playback music!")  

        } else if  capability.contains(SKCloudServiceCapability.addToCloudMusicLibrary) {  
            print("The user has an Apple Music subscription, can playback music AND can add to the Cloud Music Library")  

        } else {  
            print("The user doesn't have an Apple Music subscription available. Now would be a good time to prompt them to buy one?")  

        }  
    }  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

it's bit arithmetic

```
.musicCatalogPlayback(1 << 0 = 1) | . addToCloudMusicLibrary(1 << 8 = 256) = 257
```

use

```
swift:

case SKCloudServiceCapability.addToCloudMusicLibrary|SKCloudServiceCapability.musicCatalogPlayback:{
    //code
}break;
```

oc:

```
case SKCloudServiceCapabilityAddToCloudMusicLibrary|SKCloudServiceCapabilityMusicCatalogPlayback:{
            //code
        }break;
```